# Orthogonal transformations in 2-D

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, orthogonality

Why do orthogonal matrices represent rotations /reflections and isometries and what do unitary matrices represent in group theory?

Answer (score 1):

If you think about n-by-n matrices as homomorphisms from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, then invertible matrices represent isomorphisms. The orthogonal matrices are a special class of isomorphisms that preserve the Euclidean length, that is if $\mathbf{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $A \in O(n)$ (where $O(n)$ is the orthogonal group--the set of orthogonal matrices) then $|| A \mathbf{v} || = || \mathbf{v} ||$.

Another definition of an orthogonal matrix is a matrix $A$ such that $A^{-1} = A^T$. Using the definition of the Euclidean inner product, it's easy to see that an orthogonal matrix defined this way preserves length

$$ ||A\mathbf{v}|| = \sqrt{(A\mathbf{v})^TA\mathbf{v}} = \sqrt{\mathbf{v}^TA^TA\mathbf{v}} = \sqrt{\mathbf{v}^TA^{-1}A\mathbf{v}} = \sqrt{\mathbf{v}^T\mathbf{v}} = ||\mathbf{v}||$$

In general, distance-preserving functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ can geometrically interpreted as compositions of translations, reflections, and rotations. Since isomorphisms between vector spaces must fix the origin, the orthogonal group cannot represent translations, and only represents reflections and rotations.

Unitary matrices are simply the complex analogue of the orthogonal matrices, and are the Euclidian distance-preserving isomorphisms from $\mathbb{C}^n$ to $\mathbb{C}^n$.